# how to Find the password of all wlan via netsh

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, wifi, netsh

I want to find out the name of all my wlan along with their password:

```
ssid : password
```

With the search I made, I realized that it is possible to extract passwords individually with netsh
But I need a batch script to get the name of each wlan, and extract and display the password for each name
For example, I want the output to be like this:

```
ModemN1 :  123987654af
IsntModem : PASSw0rd!23
```

**If you have another solution besides netsh, please tell me**

can find all wlan profile:

```
C:> netsh wlan show profile

Profiles on interface Wi-Fi:

Group policy profiles (read only)
---------------------------------
    <None>

User profiles
-------------
    All User Profile     : ModemN1
    All User Profile     : IsntModem
```

It should extract two **ModemN1**, **IsntModem** strings here
And for each of these strings, put the strings in this command:
`netsh wlan show profile <WLAN_NAME> key=clear`

```
C:> netsh wlan show profile IsntModem key=clear

Profile IsntModem on interface Wi-Fi:
=======================================================================

Applied: All User Profile

Profile information
-------------------
    Version                : 1
    Type                   : Wireless LAN
    Name                   : IsntModem
    Control options        :
        Connection mode    : Connect automatically
        Network broadcast  : Connect even if this network is not broadcasting
        AutoSwitch         : Do not switch to other networks
        MAC Randomization  : Disabled

Connectivity settings
---------------------
    Number of SSIDs        : 1
    SSID name              : "IsntModem"
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : [ Any Radio Type ]
    Vendor extension          : Not present

Security settings
-----------------
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : GCMP
    Security key           : Present
    Key Content            : PASSw0rd!23

Cost settings
-------------
    Cost                   : Unrestricted
    Congested              : No
    Approaching Data Limit : No
    Over Data Limit        : No
    Roaming                : No
    Cost Source            : Default
```

and extract the password from here

Thank you for helping me ❤

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure this has been parsed before though couldn't find a [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) duplicate for it, you can give this a try, seems to work fairly well:

```
netsh wlan show profile |
    Select-String '(?<=All User Profile\s+:\s).+' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $wlan = $_.Matches.Value
        $passw = netsh wlan show profile $wlan key=clear |
            Select-String '(?<=Key Content\s+:\s).+'

        [pscustomobject]@{
            Name     = $wlan
            Password = $passw.Matches.Value
        }
    }
```

For the regex descriptions:

- https://regex101.com/r/v9T4pB/2 for the first one
- https://regex101.com/r/xPeEDy/2 for the second one

Answer (score 1):

There is a fairly simple script you can run.

After the script runs, close PowerShell and proceed to your desktop, there will be a new .txt file titled "Log". In this log is a copy of every SSID on one side and the Key(s) right next to them in a separate column.

```
(netsh wlan show profiles) | Select-String “\:(.+)$” | %{$name=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{(netsh wlan show profile name=”$name” key=clear)} | Select-String “Key Content\W+\:(.+)$” | %{$pass=$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value.Trim(); $_} | %{[PSCustomObject]@{ PROFILE_NAME=$name;PASSWORD=$pass }} | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Log.txt
```

Comment: [wifi-passwords.ps1](https://gist.github.com/CybersamuraiDK/6e0be5c0c47165228895079efa8d98ec)